# Custom attributes for user registration Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I need to add custom fields in the registration of a new user from Keycloak, and I saw from the documentation that this is possible if I enable the User Profile Enabled option, but this option is not appearing for me in the master realm with the admin user.

I'm using Keycloak version 21.1.1 and saw the information about this field in the link [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#enabling-the-user-profile).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to enable it first. From the documentation you linked:

> Declarative User Profile is Technology Preview and is not fully supported. This feature is disabled by default.
> To enable start the server with `--features=preview` or `--features=declarative-user-profile`

Good luck.